# How to Center SingleChildScrollView but make background stretch to fill screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am use Flutter for web for make website. I want make webpage scroll when user scroll down like normal website.

I am try use `Stack` so I can place custom background behind widgets. This background must scroll when user scroll (must stick to widgets in front so background change).

(I cannot set background color using `Scaffold`  because my background is use `CustomPainter`)

But I want center the widgets on webpage, so I wrap `SingleChildScrollView` in `Center` widget. But now on large horizontal screen the `CustomPaintWidget()` is not fill screen (there is blank space). I  have try replace my `CustomPaintWidget()` with `Container` to test, but same issue.

Here my code:

```
Center(
     child: SingleChildScrollView(
     child:Stack(children: <Widget>[
           CustomPaintWidget(),
           Widgets(),
     ],),
```

Anyone know solution?

How to center widgets but also make background stretch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) by definition shriknwraps it's child.

What you should try is

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
     child: ConstrainedBox(
       //Use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height for max Height
       constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
       child: Center(
         child: //Widget,
      ),
     ),
   );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! MediaQuery.of(context).**size**.height. But now nothing is show on screen.

Comment: Nice! tried some other complex solutions but they didn't work. But this did!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomPaintWidget(),
        Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Widgets(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have try this solution. It solve background stretch, but now background is not move when scroll. So background stay in same place but widget on top are move. This not like normal webpage.

Comment: do you need to scrolls?, one for the Widgets() and one for the background?

Comment: I not think need 2 scrolls. I just want make webpage for example: codemagic.io . There is background and foreground. When scroll, both are move (they are stick together).

Comment: you're looking for a parallax effect

Answer (score 0):

read that post, I think is all you need https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/spike-parallax-in-flutter-seven-lines-of-code-16a1890d8d32

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer but s.o may need it in future
You have to use `Stack`

for instance:

your MainClass:

```
 class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
        ScrollViewClass(),
        Column(
          children: [
         //YOUR ITEMS
  ]),
);
```

ScrollviewClass:

```
    class ScrollViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
   _ScrollViewClassState createState() => _ScrollViewClassState();
   }

   class _ScrollViewClassState extends State<ScrollViewClass> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 260, bottom: 100),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                  //Use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height for max Height
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                    
//ADD YOUR ITEMS LIKE IMAGE, TEXT, CARD ETC...

Center(child: Image.asset('assets/app_name.png')),
                              Center(child: Image.asset('assets/app_name.png')),
                              Center(child: Image.asset('assets/app_name.png')),
                              Center(child: Image.asset('assets/app_name.png')),
                              Center(child: Text('fdgdfg')),
                              Center(child: Text('fdgdfg')),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the OP's scenario, but for others - If there is something above your scroll view, using the full height of the page will cause the scrollview to scroll prematurely, because the combined height of the widgets is now greater than the page height. Use `LayoutBuilder` instead of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`.

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: ((context, constraints) {
  return SingleChildScrollView(
    child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
        child: Center(child: child)),
  );
})
```